# A tour of my tower

Tags: riddle, story

A new riddle - I don't think it should give anyone too much trouble!

> Let me show you my building - do you like the lovely green carpet?
>   All the rooms are connected by these hallways.
>
> Downstairs are the archives - we keep all our records there.
>   It takes a while to find anything, but it's a safe place for them.
>
> Across the hall are the libraries, much easier to navigate but a bit small.
>   The librarian is often heading downstairs to swap out books.
>
> The generator is near too, we use a lot of power!
>   If that goes, then we're all lost.
>
> The artists studio is next door, he loves to paint and draw.
>   Sometimes he gets a bit hot though, so he'll open the windows for a breeze.
>
> Down from him is the recording studio,
>   It gets a bit noisy in there.
>
> The radio room is at the end of the corridor.
>   Operators are constantly in communication.
>
> This is my office, in the middle of it all.
>   Everyone brings me work to do.
>
> In days past I would be alone in this room, but now I have a few helpers with me.
>   Sometimes it still feels like we are doing two things at once though.
>
> Who am I, and where do I work?

---

<sub>A complete answer should identify all the various rooms. Enjoy!</sub>

---

<sub>Update: Slight edit to clarify a potential ambiguity</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are most likely

> A computer processor (probably dual core - "doing two things at once")

You work at

> A computer (probably a desktop)

Title - A tour of my tower

> PC's or Desktop computers have been called towers of mini-towers (comment from @tmpearce) - show how it incorporates the title

Let me show you my building - do you like the lovely green carpet?
All the rooms are connected by these hallways.

> Green carpet is motherboard

Downstairs are the archives - we keep all our records there.
It takes a while to find anything, but it's a safe place for them.

> Hard drive

The generator is there too, we use a lot of power! 
If that goes, then we're all lost.

> Power supply

Across the hall are the libraries, much easier to navigate but a bit small.
The librarian is often heading downstairs to swap out books.

> RAM

The artists studio is next door, he loves to paint and draw.
Sometimes he gets a bit hot though, so he'll open the windows for a breeze.

> Graphics Card (comment from @DavidLewis) - Gets hot often, has dedicated cooling

Down from him is the recording studio, 
It gets a bit noisy in there.

> Sound Card

The radio room is at the end of the corridor. 
Operators are constantly in communication.

> Network card

This is my office, in the middle of it all. 
Everyone brings me work to do.

> CPU

Thoughts

> I've taken apart a few PC's but never built one from scratch. That would have helped for a more complete answer. Thanks for your patience and assistance.

Comment: Nice answer so far! You have one thing incorrect (I think you know which one) - sweet dreams and once it's polished up then it's all yours.

Comment: The only thing to tidy up would be rot13(Gur negvfgf fghqvb fubhyq or gur tencuvpf pneq. Vg trgf ubg fb bsgra unf qrqvpngrq pbbyvat)

Comment: Agree @DavidLewis, I was going to say the same thing

Comment: The title also makes sense with this interpretation, I recommend incorporating it into the answer.